# Pie charts in Qgis

Tags: r, charts, gis, qgis, pie-chart

I have this problem:
I would like to create a pie chart from a column of a attribute table, and I would like to see this pie chart above the map. The column contains names not nubers...
I work with marine species distribution data and I built a database of records of many many species...
In the specific, I have a column, called 'species', where there are many records (names) of some marine species. Several species may have many records, other species may have only a few numbers of records, so my objective is to graphically see the distribuition of records among the species.
If build a pie chart is a very time consuming procedure, I'd be happy to create a new column of the attribute table with the numbers of different species per year (see the attachments) or to try a totally new approach with R.
Thankyou for your help
img1 http://postimg.org/image/rn56c8l4z/
img2 http://postimg.org/image/e6918ynmj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll most probably get many answers that pie charts are *evil* because they distort perception.

But along with better alternatives, namely stacked bar charts, you find [code examples here](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/pie.html)

and, as always,

> ? pie

helps.

You may need to summarize your factor first, e.g. by `table`.

Comment: I know as make a pie chart in R, im not sure as to do on a shapefile... But if possible I want to do all in qgis...

Comment: You mean you want to have lots of little pies instead of the dots on the map?

Comment: I want a pie made with the numbers of records. For example tot records:10'000. 1st species records: 5'000, 2nd species records: 2'500, 3rd species records: 2'500... So the pie will be formed by 5000, 2500 and 2500 records i.e. 50%, 25% and 25%

Comment: Then go for `table` first, and produce the `pie` from the results of `table`.